# Laravel 4 admin route same as admin folder

Tags: laravel, directory, laravel-routing

i have an /admin folder and i cant delete becaus there are old files linked externaly and i need to use the /admin route.
When i use the /admin route i have a loop, if i rename the admin folder, it works, but i cant do that permanently.
If i use another route like /admin/anything, it works.

How can i have the folder and the route work together.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::post('admin/login/valida', ['before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getValidar']);
Route::get('admin/login', 'AdminController@Login');
Route::get('admin/asociarmenuarchivo', 'AdminController@Asociarmenuarchivo');
Route::get('admin/disenosnuevos', 'AdminController@disenosNuevos');
Route::get('admin/disenosnuevooantiguo', 'AdminController@switchDisenos');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@getIndex');
```

The last one is the only route that doesnt work.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}  !/cm/.*
    #RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}  !/admin/.*
    RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}  !/correo/.*

    RewriteRule !^/?admin index.php [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorised"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the slash rewrite, the solution was:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}  !/admin/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```